# cmake missing fortran module dependency in preprocessor directive

Tags: cmake, fortran

I'm run into a problem where Cmake is missing a dependency. The code in question looks like.

```
        SUBROUTINE foo
        USE A
  #ifdef C
        USE B
  #endif
        ...
```

It looks like the preprocessor blocked portion is getting excluded when generating the dependencies. This is causing an error because module B never gets built before this source file. How can I resolve this?

Update:

I'm setting the preprocessor define here.

```
add_library (abc STATIC ${abc_sources})
set_target_properties (abc PROPERTIES COMPILE_FLAGS "${BUILD_FLAGS} -D C")
```

Comment: Are you defining `C`?  If not, then it isn't a dependency.

Comment: As a sanity test, does it find the `B` dependency if the preprocessor direcectives are omitted completely?

Comment: Yes. If I comment out the preprocessor statements it finds it ok.

Comment: Could you show how you are defining the sources for the executable from your CMakeLists.txt?

Comment: Instead of adding the definition with `COMPILE_FLAGS`, try the separate `ADD_DEFINITIONS` command: `ADD_DEFINITIONS(-DC)`.  Note that omitting the space is important.

Comment: The issue with that is I only want to add that define for a specific target. I compiling this source twice. Once without the define to produce one library and a second time with it defined to produce a second library. 'add_definitions()' will add that for every target.

Comment: True.  The issue is that I think CMake uses the `ADD_DEFINITIONS` to determine how to scan for dependencies, whereas the `COMPILE_FLAGS` are simply added to the flag list.  You may have to figure out a way to remove definitions for the library that doesn't use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out. The correct solution is use

```
set_target_properties (abc PROPERTIES COMPILE_DEFINITIONS "C")
```

`COMPILE_DEFINITIONS` is the `set_target_properties` anaglog to `add_definitions`.

Comment: Glad you found the answer!  I was unaware of the individual `COMPILE_DEFINITIONS`